# What are some good resources for finding quality information about carseats?

Tags: toddler, safety, car-seat

It is time for me to start thinking about transitioning my twin boys from their infant car seats to larger ones.  I am trying to do research on the different brands of carseats, their safety information, size requirements, and so on.

Where are the best places to find quality information and reviews on carseats?

Update:
Just wanted to say that I did all my research, chose a carseat, went to the store to buy it, and ended up buying a completely different one.  :)  Still a good one but not what I had planned to get.

Comment: What were the reasons that you ended up buying something else than what your research suggested?

Comment: When we got there DH looked at the one that I had picked out and decided that it was to expensive and heavy.  The one that we ended up getting had all the same features and because we needed 2 of them we saved quite a bit of money.  When I got home and looked it up it is just as safe as the one I had picked out.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of good government (U.S.) sites:

http://www.safercar.gov/

http://www.nhtsa.gov/Laws+&+Regulations/Child+Passenger+Safety

Some retailers have more user-friendly guides:

Babies 'R' Us:
http://www.toysrus.com/shop/index.jsp?categoryId=2964251

Target:
http://www.target.com/Car-Seat-Selector-Seats-Baby/b/ref=sc_iw_r_2_0_1041910?node=2380019011

Those are the sites I have used before purchasing carseats.

Answer (score 3):

[Car-seat.org](http://www.car-seat.org/)

There are hundreds of thousand of Certified Child Passenger Safety Technicians on this forum and they will answer your questions and provide accurate information.

Answer (score 1):

**Ask your national automobile club.**

I think in USA there's something called AAA. In Europe there are national organizations that cooperate. They also do scientific testing and crash testing with car seats, and they share these findings. I know that the results published in Denmark and Austria are trustworthy and I expect any such organization to be able to give you a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I like Steven Levitt's view in this [TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/steven_levitt_on_child_carseats.html).

Comment: Can you please add a summary of Levitt's view?

Answer (score 1):

[which.co.uk](http://which.co.uk) does some very good reviews (more tests than are required by law), but it is a subscription service.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://carseatblog.com/carseatblogcoms-recommended-car-seats/) was useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used Consumer Reports. I thought they provided a lot of useful information.

http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/babies-kids/baby-toddler/car-seats/index.htm?CMP=OTC-NAV4